# Includes, joins and select in rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get a really simple query with rails 4 but I'm facing unexpected issues...

I have a `Country` model with a translations table (via [globalize gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)). I want to get every country name in the current locale, the country id and a `short_code` I've stored in my `Country` model.

My first approach to this was this sentence:

```
countries = Country.select('countries.id, countries.short_code,
        country_translations.name').joins(:translations)
```

This generates this SQL:

```
SELECT countries.id, countries.short_code, country_translations.name 
    FROM `countries` INNER JOIN `country_translations` 
    ON `country_translations`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id`
```

That seems to be a correct query and it gets the data that I want if I run it in a db console. The problem comes because I need to serialize `countries`. It runs a query for each country:

```
SELECT `country_translations`.* FROM `country_translations` WHERE `country_translations`.`country_id` = 1  [["country_id", 1]]
[...]
SELECT `country_translations`.* FROM `country_translations` WHERE `country_translations`.`country_id` = 238  [["country_id", 238]]
SELECT `country_translations`.* FROM `country_translations` WHERE `country_translations`.`country_id` = 239  [["country_id", 239]]
```

To avoid the n+1 problem, I try to `include` translations on query:

```
countries = Country.select('countries.id, countries.short_code, 
    country_translations.name').includes(:translations).joins(:translations)
```

This works like a charm and returns everything in just one query. The problem is it gets every attribute from `country` and `country_translations` too, ignoring the select statement!

```
SELECT countries.id, countries.short_code, country_translations.name, 
    `countries`.`id` AS t0_r0, `countries`.`population` AS t0_r1,
    `countries`.`short_code` AS t0_r2, 
    `countries`.`lat` AS t0_r3,
    `countries`.`lng` AS t0_r4, 
    `countries`.`range` AS t0_r5,
    `countries`.`tilt` AS t0_r6, 
    `countries`.`heading` AS t0_r7,
    `countries`.`country_code_short` AS t0_r8, 
    `countries`.`date_format` AS t0_r9, 
    ...
    `countries`.`created_at` AS t0_r12, 
    `countries`.`updated_at` AS t0_r13,
    `country_translations`.`id` AS t1_r0, 
    `country_translations`.`country_id` AS t1_r1, 
    `country_translations`.`locale` AS t1_r2, 
    `country_translations`.`created_at` AS t1_r3, 
    `country_translations`.`updated_at` AS t1_r4, 
    `country_translations`.`name` AS t1_r5, 
    `country_translations`.`language` AS t1_r6, 
    `country_translations`.`currency` AS t1_r7, 
    `country_translations`.`capital` AS t1_r8, 
    `country_translations`.`slug` AS t1_r9 
    FROM `countries` 
    INNER JOIN `country_translations` 
    ON `country_translations`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id`
```

This brings another problem because serialization is more complex with so many fields...

What am I missing? How can I get just those three fields I need?

Comment: Can you show how you are serializing the countries? Try passing an alias to the translation name `countries = Country.select('countries.id, countries.short_code, country_translations.name as name')` and use `country["name"]` when looping over countries.

Comment: I'm using ActiveModel serializer, but I can reproduce it too by getting `countries.first`, `countries.second`... each time it runs a new query...

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're calling `country.name` and expecting the `name` *attribute* from the ActiveRecord result, whereas the globalize gem is calling the `name` *method* - which fires the n+1.

Using ActiveRecord's [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method is one way to address the n+1 as you've mentioned, but has the nasty side effect of negating `select` statements and building larger ActiveRecord::Relation objects than are required. Plus, you're already selecting the fields you need the efficient way.

[AbM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2697183/abm) above points to the solution; however `country_translations.name` is already aliased as `name` in your query, for clarification I would suggest something like:

```
countries = Country.select([
  'countries.id', 
  'countries.short_code',
  'country_translations.name AS country_translation_name'
  ])
```

When iterating over `countries`, you can now call:

```
country.id                       # => 840
country.short_code               # => "US"
country.country_translation_name # => "United States of America"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

It seems a good point but I've tried it and I'm still getting lots of unexpected fields:
`"countries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "country_code": "TUN",
      "name": "Tunisia",
      "language": "Arabic",
      "currency": "Tunisian dinar",
      "capital": "Tunis",
      "slug": "tunisia"
    },`

Comment: Without seeing any code: if you're using ActiveModel serializer you probably have a line like `attributes :id, :short_code, :name`. You'll need to specify (in our case) a `country_translation_name` attribute and likely access it using `object.country_translation_name`. See [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#overriding-attribute-methods)